# Run bash script with prompts on startup, then start browser

Tags: bash, scripts, google-chrome, gnome-terminal, autostart

I am creating a standard linux image for my customers, which I want to distribute to them as a backup.

I have written a bash script - `verifysetup.sh` which checks whether the machine has already been set up. If it has, it succeeds silently, but if not lets them enter their account details, then downloads their configuration files and updated executables.

Each time the machine starts in the default user account, I need the following to happen:

1. Run `verifysetup.sh` (in a terminal so they can respond to prompts)
2. Run chrome (pointed at localhost to display their UI)
3. Close the terminal

To achieve this, I've:

1. Created a `.desktop`file in `~/.config/autostart/`as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -x bash -c "bash ~/bin/startui.sh"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_GB]=Flow
Name=Flow
Comment[en_GB]=
Comment=
```

1. Created a script `~/bin/startui.sh` (see below) which runs the `veryifysetup.sh` script then starts and disowns Chrome

```bsh
# Run the interactive setup script
bash ~/bin/verifysetup.sh

# "Start Chrome and disown"
(google-chrome --user-data-dir=r=~/chrome/chrome-1 --start-fullscreen --window-position=0,0 http://localhost </dev/null &>/dev/null &)
```

If I open a terminal and run `bash ~/bin/startui.sh` directly, then close the terminal, this works perfectly - Chrome launches and keeps running, even when I close the terminal window.

However when the script runs on startup, or if I emulate this by invoking `gnome-terminal -x bash ~/bin/startui.sh` from a terminal window, the Chrome window disappears as soon as the script exits (if I put a `sleep 5` statement at the end of `startui.sh` I can clearly see the browser start then shut down when the terminal window closes.)

I've also tried disowning using `disown -a -h` after launching Chrome, but with the same result. Interestingly, if I run `jobs -l` before that, I don't see any jobs listed.

So why is Chrome closing at the end of the script when launched via a new `gnome-terminal` instance but not when it is run directly? And is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This seems overly complex. Since your UI is under your control, why not just do all this under its control? Always boot to your UI, which checks `verifysetup.sh` and asks for account details if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. I'm not sure what you mean when you say the UI is under my control. The UI runs in Chrome, served from a docker container running on localhost. The setup scripts carry out the necessary steps to configure and download the necessary containers. Maybe I'm being naive but running an interactive script then starting Chrome doesn't feel enormously complex - at least in principle.

Comment: There's a relevant answer that covers this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/310780). Can't figure how to use as the link for an "already answered" flag as I'm on the mobile app.